# I need to keep track of a specific amount of geoJSON updates from a varying number of vehicles

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, geojson

These updates will come from $scope.vehicles which will include .geometry and further, .coordinates which is an array of just two elements. Lat and lon. I need to keep track of the coordinates so I can determine if any specific vehicle is moving or if the vehicle is "on a break." I'm thinking of implementing a circular que but that's really where I get stuck. I'm not sure how to get the right vehicles to update the right arrays and to constantly have them update. The vehicles location is pulled every 10 seconds to the front end so that a marker can be redrawn. I just need to keep track of each one of these for around 40 updates or so.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You would be in a much better situation if you had some sort of ID in your features properties in the first place. Otherwise you can try assuming that each feature previous position is the nearest point from previous data; but you will be lost when all vehicles are moving close together. Even more when new vehicles are popping out of nowhere. At least if you only want to detect absence of movement, you can focus on features that do not move at all, and ignore others.

Comment: &scope.vehicles does have a vehicles._id feature.